# neo4j subtract elements of a path

Tags: path, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying use this query in Cypher(Neo4):

```
MATCH p=(n:BP)-[:Selected]-(g:MOL)-[:Selected]-(e:BP) WHERE n.NameExp='Bos_RM' AND e.NameExp='Jac_RM' AND NONE(x IN nodes(p) WHERE x.NameExp='Jac_AGM' OR x.NameExp='Bos_SM')  RETURN n,e,g limit 100
```

That is, I would like exclude some nodes in path(p) that have properties 'Jac_AGM' and 'Jac_SM'. I'm using Neo4j version 2.1.3.

Thanks!
Best wishes,
R.

Comment: Hey did you arrive at any solution?

Answer (score 1):

According to your query, you have already mentioned the NameExp attrib values for n and e Nodes. So its evident the nodes with the given names that you wish to be not included are among the set of g:MOL labeled nodes which you can be simply eliminated like below...

```
MATCH p=(n:BP)-[:Selected]-(g:MOL)-[:Selected]-(e:BP) 
WHERE n.NameExp='Bos_RM' AND e.NameExp='Jac_RM' 
AND NOT g.NameExp IN ['Jac_AGM','Jac_SM']
RETURN n,e,g limit 100
```

Answer (score 0):

there is also an explicit option to `filter` nodes in the collection `p`:

```
MATCH p=(n:BP)-[:Selected]-(g:MOL)-[:Selected]-(e:BP)
WITH FILTER(x IN nodes(p): x.NameExp NOT IN ['Jac_AGM','Bos_SM']) AS pp, n, e
WHERE n.NameExp='Bos_RM' AND e.NameExp='Jac_RM'
RETURN n,e,g limit 100
```

[source](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/neo4j-cypher-translating-19)

Comment: thanks for your attention, but the code doesn't work. I'm beginner in Neo4J. I would like exclude in path some nodes that have properties: BP.NameExp = 'Jac_AGM' and nodes that contain BP.NameExp='Bos_SM'. Best wishes,

Comment: yes, i didnt have time to check the code, i wrote it from memory. but you can play with the `filter` option according to the docs yourself.